# How do I dynamically cast from a void * pointer generically?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, dynamic-cast

```
class BASE {
public:
    virtual ~BASE() {}
    void lamp() {
        cout << "\nBASE CLASS";
    }
};

class DERIVED : public BASE {
public:
    void fun();
};

void DERIVED::fun() {
    cout << "\nDERIVED CLASS!";
}

int main() {

    BASE * pbase = new DERIVED; //BASE CLASS POINTER
    void * vbase = pbase;       //VOID POINTER TAKING BASE POINTER 
    DERIVED * pder;             //DERIVED CLASS POINTER

    //pder = static_cast<DERIVED *>(vbase);  //THIS WORKS
    pder = dynamic_cast<DERIVED *>(vbase);   //THIS DOESN'T
    pder->lamp();
    pder->fun();

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to dynamically cast the `void*` pointer to the derived class pointer, I get the following error:

> cannot dynamic_cast 'vbase' (of type 'void*') to type 'class DERIVED*' (source is not a pointer to class)

I've searched StackOverflow and followed advice by implementing a virtual function in the base class to avoid the error.  What am I doing wrong?
Is this possible at all?

My overall intention is to cast ANY incoming Object type into a Derived class type using a `void*` pointer.  I hope you understand what I mean.

For example:

```
void dynamicCast(void * vptr)
{
    BASE * pbase = new DERIVED;
    DERIVED * pder;

    pder = dynamic_cast<DERIVED *>(vbase);
}
```

I should be able to pass any type of pointer to the `dynamicCast` function and it should be converted to the derived class pointer.

Comment: What you're asking for is fundamentally impossible. Why are you trying to do this? Perhaps there's another way to achieve that.

Comment: The answer is: you don't.

Comment: `void *` pointer cannot be safely cast to `BASE *` or `DERIVED *` because they are not related. You cannot use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` for this purpose.

Comment: @hvd This is an assignment given to me. I have to implement a various linked list functionalities using an header file. The function declarations are in the header and the definitions are in a separate .cpp file. The function to Insert a new Node must take a void pointer as the user can give any-type of object as a Node with varying number of members in the file with main() function. i hope you understand what I'm trying to say. TL:DR. 3 Files: A header to hold function  declarations, a .cpp file to definitions for the functions and another .cpp file where the functions are implemented.

Comment: @VigneshGunasekaran Sounds like you don't need to cast at all, sounds like you can just leave it a `void *`.

Comment: You can store a void * in a list, you don't need to cast it to anything. You need a class to store the void *

Comment: @GarrGodfrey  But I get an error when I try to access the values stored in the memory location. ** Left of -> must point to a Class/Struct/Union/generic Type**

Comment: That is a different bug.

Comment: then don't do that.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey So Is it impossible to implement a generic linked list which can take any type of object?

Comment: no, it's easy. you just cannot spy on the data passed to you. don't use the void* as a node, it is data attached to the node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a design or/and comprehension problem

As explained you can not `dynamic_cast` from a `void*`.

Why? Because `dynamic_cast` needs some **Run-Time Type Information (RTTI)** to do the cast (see [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/RTTI) for further details). From `void*` alone, the C++ code has no chance to know where this information is. The minimum is to use a pointer to an object having such RTTI information.

This information is created and bounded to any class having at least one **virtual method**. If there is no virtual method this information is not included. That is the reason why this **does not** work:

```
struct A
{
};

struct B : A
{
};

int main()
{
  B  b;
  A *a = &b;

  dynamic_cast<B *>(a);  // YOUR COMPILE TIME ERROR
}
```

A fix is to add a virtual method to A. Here I have added a virtual destructor as [this is generally a good thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

```
struct A
{
   virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : A
{
};

int main()
{
  B  b;
  A *a = &b;

  dynamic_cast<B *>(a);  // OK
}
```

Also note that `dynamic_cast` allows you to check that the conversion was legal.

For instance we can add a **C** class and check:

```
struct C 
{
};

int main()
{
  B  b;
  A *a = &b;

  assert(dynamic_cast<B *>(a)!=nullptr); // OK
  assert(dynamic_cast<C *>(a)==nullptr); // OK can not cast A to C 
}
```

This kind of *run-time* operations are not free. If you search for maximum speed to can use this trick:

```
assert(dynamic_cast<B *>(a)!=nullptr);
B* b=static_cast<B*>(a);
```

In debug mode you will check if everything is ok and in release mode with the `-DNDEBUG` flag to remove the `assert` you will only use the `static_cast`

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a pointer to an object type into a pointer to void, the **only** valid conversion for that void pointer is **back to its original type**. You can't use `dynamic_cast` on a pointer to `void` because `void` is not a polymorphic type, so you do it with a `static_cast`. Like this:

```
BASE *pbase = new DERIVED;
void *vbase = pbase; // Ok; implicit conversion to void*
BASE *pbase1 = static_cast<BASE*>(vbase); // the cast is required
```

Once you've gotten back the pointer to `BASE`, of course, you can use `dynamic_cast` to convert it to a pointer to the derived type:

```
DERIVED *pder = dynamic_cast<DERIVED*>(pbase1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `dynamic_cast` on a `void *`.

From the specification, for `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`:

> If T is a pointer type, v shall be a prvalue of **a pointer to complete class type**, and the result is a prvalue of type T. ...

What you should do is to let all your classes derive from the same polymorphic base class (which has at least one virtual function) `BASE`, and use `BASE *` instead of `void *`.

Comment: This is an assignment given to me. I have to implement a various linked list functionalities using an header file. The function declarations are in the header and the definitions are in a separate .cpp file. The function to Insert a new Node must take a void pointer as the user can give any-type of object as a Node with varying number of members in the file with main() function. i hope you understand what I'm trying to say. TL:DR. 3 Files: A header to hold function declarations, a .cpp file to definitions for the functions and another .cpp file where the functions are implemented.

Comment: Do you need to access the void * in your linked list, or only the user of the linked list need to know about what it inside the void *?

Comment: But void *vbase = pbase. It has the Base pointer right? or Am i wrong?

Comment: If your linked list needs to access some functions inside the void *, then put them in a base class and every thing inherits from that base. You cannot use void * here and must use the base *. If not, the user of list needs to keep track of the void * and use the appropriate cast to cast it back. but not dynamic_cast.

Comment: I need to access the void * in my Linked list but what type of object it points to is decided by the user.

Comment: Type information is very important in C++, using void * you lost it. They may have the same internal value, but the behavior is different.

Comment: If you do not know what type of object it is, how can you access it? What if it is just a int * or char *?

Comment: The Node object must be a class or a struct and they can carry varying number of members. The reason i tried to use void pointer in he first place was to accommodate for the varying number of members. For example, first node is a class containing 3 members and the second is a different struct object  containing two members and I should be able to insert the created node seamlessly.

Comment: What ever your intention is, casting to void loses type information. And there will be no way to check what type it originally is. Void * can be cast to a pointer to class types using static_cast, but you must make sure that they are actually the same type yourself. C++ cannot prevent any error introduced by the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Your generic linked list should be like this:

```
class Node
{
    Node* next;
    void* vdata;
}
```

That's the only data structure strictly required, but you might want a circular list, or a base node to keep track of the end of the list, or a doubly-linked list.

Caller passes you a void*, you create a new node, set "vdata" and add the node to your list.

Comment: Note, the caller will have to know when to free the data pointed to by void*.